# Adding "New" fields once existing fields are filled in

Tags: java, forms, swing, user-interface, field

I've programmed in Java before, but I'm fairly new to creating GUI's, and as such, am new to Swing. I'm trying to create a mastermind-like game where the user has a certain number of guesses to determine the secret code. The problem I am having is finding a way to have the input fields for the potentially varying number of turns appear one at a time. If the user gets 10 guesses, only the input field and submit button for the first guess appear to begin with. After submitting the first guess, the second field and submit button should appear. After the second is submitted, the 3rd set appears, and so on and so forth until the user either gets the code correct or exhausts all his turns.

I've got a solid game, as it worked beautifully as a CLI-based application, but I really want to turn it into a GUI, and this one aspect is bogging me down.

Thanks in advance for any help that might be provided.

I received feedback that my scope was too broad or something of that nature. I'm not sure how I can make this question any less broad. What I want to do is have a guess field in a window and a submit button that replicate a specified number of times or until the guess is correct. For example, The game in question is similar to mastermind. When the game starts, one input box and one submit button display. If the user gets it wrong, a new guess box and a new submit button display for the second guess. This process continues until the user has guessed X number of times or until the user gets the code right. I know how to add fields statically at the beginning, but I want to form to be dynamic and change as the game progresses, and this is specifically what I am having trouble getting to happen. I can't even find where to begin looking for the answer. I have been through the Swing documentation, and many other tutorials and resources for both Java and Swing, and I have yet to find or devise a clear solution.

If it helps in narrowing down where to focus, I was able to get the game up and running with just 1 input box, but it didn't provide a look and feel that was sufficiently removed from the CLI version for my taste.

Comment: You need to start somewhere.. and if you have a problem.. ask a precise question... I suggest the Swing tutorial.. It's a great place to start on their homepage..

Comment: Too many possible ways including using a JTable and adding rows, using a JPanel that uses a GridLayout and adding sub JPanels... just experiment, play with it, create.

Comment: I have started somewhere. I've got a working CLI-based java program, and I'm trying to convert it to GUI. The only issue I am having is making a dynamic form. All the help and tutorials I have found only show making static forms, where all parts are visible from the beginning. I need a form that changes based on user input.

Comment: For argument's sake, does specifying that I want a JPanel containing a text field and a button that spawns a new JPanel containing a text field and a button if the guess submitted isn't correct narrow it down sufficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic requirement for the core UI is a field and a label.  This forms the basic `QuestionPanel`

Start by creating a custom component, extending from something like `JPanel`.  To this panel, add the label and field in what ever manner you want.

Provide setters and getters to adjust the information on the panel (such setting the question and getting the guess).

Create a `JPanel`, this using a `BorderLayout`.  To the `BorderLayout.SOUTH` position, you will want to add your `Submit` `JButton` (you might find you get a better result if you first add the `JButton` to another `JPanel` and add that to the first).

Add the `QuestionPane` to the `BorderLayout.CENTER` position.  Here you now have the basic layout requirements for your UI.

You will want to add an `ActionListener` to the `JButton` so you know when you should move to the next question.

You will want some kind of model, which contains all the questions and answers and a means by which you can set the guess or mark the question right or wrong.

Take a look at

- [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)
- [How to Write an Action Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)
- [How to Use Actions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html)
- [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html)

For more details...

Comment: It looks like this info might help, as it certainly seems more directed toward what I am trying to achieve. I will see what I can make of this next time I have a chance to sit down and work on my program.  Thanks!

Comment: Haven't had a chance to put it into practice yet, but I think between what you've suggested and the resources you've provided, I should be able to figure it out.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Simply clone both Input and Submit and add it to container .